is there a way to link oracle 11g and oracle 19c database?
We are migrating from 11g to 19c version. but we want to test if we can trasnfer a specific column from 11g to 19c upon insert.
Question?
is there a way or possible way to Connect Oracle11g and Oracle19c Database
the Scenario is Oracle11g Table1 transfer specific Columns of data to Oracle19c Table2
same column structure for both tables.
for Example:
FROM
Oracle11g
PRODUCT



Product_name
product_description




Bolt
Metal


Ziptie
Plastic



SUPPLIER



Product_name
Supplier




Bolt
Home Depot


Ziptie
Plastic



TO
Oracle19c
PRODUCT WAREHOUSE



Product_name
product_description
Supplier




Bolt
metal
Home Depot


Ziptie
plastic
Home Depot




What have you tried?  It sounds like you just want a database link.

Yes, 11.2.0.3 and up should be able to connect to 19c. Try it first, then ask if you get stuck.

yes I only want a database link but I can't find any tuotrials on google they just redirect me to migration

Update on this I found a video. its just a simple creation of datalink and I already tested it. Thanks for everyone who commented.

Yes, you can create a database link:
Documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5005.htm
Source: DB 11g
Target: DB 19c right?
So:
1 - On source you need create a user to dblink connection
2 - On target you need create an entry on tnsnames.ora pointing do 11g connection.
3 - on target 19c create dblink pointing to 11g database:
CREATE DATABASE LINK oracle11g_link CONNECT TO username IDENTIFIED BY password USING 'oracle11g_tns_entry';
4 - Insert Data using dblink:
create table test as select * FROM PRODUCT@oracle11g_link ;
ORRRRRRRRRRRR
You can use Datapump to export/import the data:
On source:
#If you choose export entire schema:
expdp "/ as sysdba" schemas=SCHEMANAME dumpfile=test.dmp
#If you choose export just one or more tables:
expdp "/ as sysdba" tables=SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME dumpfile=test.dmp
Wait export complete and copy the dumpfile to targer server (19c):
On Target:
impdp "/ as sysdba" dumpfile=test.dmp
I hope it helps.

thanks eduardo! created a link from 11g connected to 19c now.

AWESOME!!! Can u vote on my answer please? It helps me a lot. Tks my friend!
